# Using Java find installation directory of an application?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

How do I find installation directory of OpenOffice using Java Code?  I want to run it as a service when a user uses my application.

Comment: Why do you want to run OO as a service?  Are you just launching OO files for view/edit?

Comment: Na i want to use it to convert oFfice files to pDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no portable solution to this.

- On Windows you can search the registry; see [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).
- On Linux / UNIX, you can search the default installation directories, though these may vary from one distribution to the next.